# View hidden sheet, Unable to set the visible property of the worksheet class errors

Tags: excel, vba, office365, protected

I have an excel file with 4 tabs, sheet 1 has all but a few cells protected, sheet 2 was hidden, and sheet 3 was completely password protected. I need to view and edit sheet 2 however unable to do so.

I tried a solution I seen online to go to View, custom view, and add then show. This didn't work.

I will note I see my bottom bar is greyed out, nor am I able to "Insert" sheets from the top Home ribbon.
[image]  ______
[image]

I then tried the following VBA macro solution, Sheet2 name = States.

```
 ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("States").Unprotect Password:="password"
 ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("States").Visible = -1
 ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("States").Visible = False
```

However I still only get the error "Runtime error '1004': unable to set the visible property of the worksheet class"
Even in VBA properties of the sheet, if I try to set it I get the below popup

[image]

Comment: Is the workbook protected (including structure)?

Comment: @BigBen as in the "VBAProject - Project Properties" window? In that screen the the box for "Look project for viewing" is unselected. There are stars in the lower "password to view" section's fields.

Comment: As in, Review > Protect Workbook from the normal Excel ribbon.

Comment: @BigBen that allowed me to use the Unhide in the visibility menu.

Answer (score 2):

You workbook is protected.

[image]

[image]

Unprotect your workbook structure before changing the sheets' visibility.